# Firebase Realtime Database url is null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to set up a Firebase app in Android in **kotlin** ,
I have done this before and everything worked correctly before. This time though the problem was that i downloaded the `google_services.json` before creating a database.

After downloading the services.json file i created a realtime database and re downloaded the `google_services.json` file. But i cannot write to the database now

i tried to write this code

```
println(FirebaseApp.getInstance().options.toString())
```

the output of which is as follows

> I/System.out: FirebaseOptions{applicationId=1:1015286121155:android:1cced0097502849b051876, apiKey=AIzaSyDznjwsm1NGIn0bIcZewDm0Addqu_QDK4I, databaseUrl=null, gcmSenderId=1015286121155, storageBucket=standup-slack.appspot.com, projectId=standup-slack}

Also tried to do the following,

```
database.getReference("test").child("askljalsd").setValue("Hello, World!").addOnCompleteListener {
            when{
                it.isCanceled-> println("it is isCanceled ")
                it.isSuccessful-> println("it is isSuccessful")
                it.isComplete-> println("it is isComplete")
            }
        }
```

None of the cases run when the above code is executed.

I am unable to debug why my firebase database url is null even when i have updated the `google_services.json` file

Comment: Did you modify the read/write rules?

Comment: The Rules of the database are in test mode, i.e., 
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "now < 1611945000000",  // 2021-1-30
    ".write": "now < 1611945000000",  // 2021-1-30
  }
}

Comment: Well, follow the official tutorial to see which step you missed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpFDFK44pX8.

Comment: Are you sure you added the updated `google-services.json` file correctly to the app? The debug output you're showing seems to indicate otherwise, as it shows that `databaseUrl` is still `null` which shouldn't be the case for `google-services.json`  that was downloaded after creating the database in the Firebase console..

Comment: i am sure i added the correct `google-services.json` because when i open it in the editor i can see a key with `databse_url` in it and it points to the correct path

Comment: Maybe your project is still using the previous `google-services.json`, as `println(FirebaseApp.getInstance().options.toString())` is showing a null database. How about deleting the previous `google-services.json` file, if it is still in the project folder, and moving in the updated `google-services.json` file?

Comment: i have deleted the old `google-services.json` from app folder and added the new one in app folder of my android project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Android Studio Project, Deleting the **app > build** folder and clearing the gradle cache made it recognize the new `google_services.json`

Comment: There may also be errors during assembly, you need to check the free space on the disks, it may be expected to update Windows, reboot, and delete the build folder