# Firebase Database points to wrong database URL

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an Android app and trying to use Firebase Database. I tried to write data to the Database but nothing was showing up (checked via Firebase console). I have Firebase libraries in the build:

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.2.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
```

My Firebase Database URL as per Firebease console is :

```
    https://xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/
```

whereas when I get a reference to it from the code:

```
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Log.i(TAG," Reference is: "+mDatabase.toString());
```

The logcat shows below response:

```
    I/Tag:  Reference is: https://xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com
```

I also have the google-services.json file in the project which points to the same database URL shown in the Firebase console. It appears to me that Firebase has misconfigured my database somewhere which I can't see / configure.

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 5):

I recently faced a similar issue, [Firebase URL is null even after updating google_services.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65524185/firebase-realtime-database-url-is-null/65540685#65540685),
I got it working  by deleting the **build** folder of my app and rebuilding the project again

Comment: Did you do that in Firebase console? I deleted the project from Firebase console and the app still shows the wrong database URL in the logcat:
          I/Tag:  Reference is: https://xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com

Comment: In the Android Project , remove app > build directory

Comment: Man you are a life saver! Thank you so much!! I have been pulling my hairs that even when every config is passed correct, why the database url is different

Answer (score 2):

I just tested this on a new project of my own with the exact same BoM version as you, and it works fine with just the `google-services.json` file and this code:

```
final DatabaseReference ref =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Log.i("firebase", ref.toString());
ref.child("from Android").push().setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

And this runs without problems. The `Log.i` writes out:

> I/firebase: https://realtime-database-in-brussels-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app

Which is indeed the correct URL for my database, and should be a URL pretty similar to yours.

---

I'm not sure why that doesn't work for you, but you can work around it by passing the correct URL into `getInstance()` explicitly. So:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/").getReference();
```

Comment: Thank you Frank, yes it pulls correct reference this way:
I/Tag:  Reference is: https://xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app

I couldn't have guessed it, but seems like this workaround is the way to go. BTW, what can cause SDK to not read correct URL from config?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure yet. 1) Is this the only database instance you have on the project? 2) If so, did you download the configuration file **after** creating the database in the console? (my guess is "yes" on both, but I want to make sure)

Comment: Yes and yes. I checked the google-services.json file and it had everything correct but it was still pulling wrong reference, then I removed the .json file from project and played the app and it still showed the same wrong reference so I thought may be the Android Studio has wrong reference cached so I did a 'invalidate and restart' which didn't help either.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I just tested this on a project of my own, but unfortunately can't reproduce the problem. I updated my answer to reflect that, and to change the wording around the workaround.

Comment: I created new package for same app to be able to write the database and it worked, then I switched the Firebase Project to write to a common database with another app, now my configuration has gone haywire. Now I am not even able to do authentication, now I get the error "Requests from this Android client application <> are blocked", I know this looks like a different error but I believe this has connection to the above issue somehow in my Google Cloud API / Authentication configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, what helped me in Android Studio was

```
Build->Clean Project
```

and then

```
Build->Rebuild Project
```

Before this make sure that the firebase url in your google.json file is correct and you have the latest google.json file.