# FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference is getting bad address (from different region)

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I selected belgium location but when I debug the app it shows url as firebasio.com. That's the US location, belgium use firebasedatabase.app. Anybody know's why and how to fix it? I use kotlin in android-studio

Comment: I know of two possible causes here: 1) re-download the `google-services.json` after you created the database in your console, and make sure your app is using the up-to-date version. 2) explicitly specify the database URL in your application code with: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/").getReference();` I haven't been able to reproduce the latter problem myself though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65566484

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assume the DNS location appointed is the region on Firebase services. They are just "names" and do not represent fixed locations. You'll eventually be redirected to the selected datacenter as your connection is properly established. You can confirm the location by running a `traceroute` command to the resolved IP address when the app is running.

Comment: they are based on location: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations