# How do I fix this Firebase RunTime DB error where the entry into the database and authentication details are created but all the fields are null?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently trying to make a registration screen that registers a user by sending a User object contacting the user’s information to a Google Firebase Runtime DB. However, when I click on the register button, it creates an entry in the database but all the information within the user object is set to null, which is not the intended behavior. I tried playing with the firebase dependencies and modifying the rules for the Runtime DB but to no avail. I would appreciate some help fixing this.

Thank You

```
final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
String password = editTextpassword.getText().toString().trim();
final String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
final String fullName= editTextfullName.getText().toString();
final String bio = editTextBio.getText().toString().trim();
final String location = null;
final String realstatus = null; 
final ImageView profilePic = null;

progressBar.setVisibility(ViewStub.VISIBLE);
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    User user = new User(fullName, email, bio, username,location,realstatus,profilePic);

                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                            .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                         if(task.isSuccessful()){
                             Toast.makeText(Register.this,"User has been registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                             progressBar.setVisibility(ViewStub.GONE);
                             startActivity(new Intent(Register.this,Register2.class));
                         }
                         else{
                             Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Failed to Register User", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                             progressBar.setVisibility(ViewStub.GONE);
                           }
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Failed to Register User", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(ViewStub.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Error(Line 24 is the one with getReference("Users")):

```
2021-04-05 20:51:55.625 24076-24076/com.example.saucey E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.saucey, PID: 24076
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to get FirebaseDatabase instance: Specify DatabaseURL within FirebaseApp or from your getInstance() call.
        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:97)
        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:57)
        at com.example.saucey.Register$1.onComplete(Register.java:124)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: That seems unexpected. Can you show the database after the new data is added to it (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Okay sure thing.

Comment: It actually just says "null" and nothing else

Comment: In that case we'll need more debugging information from you. If you set breakpoints and run in a debugger, does the app ever reach the first `if(task.isSuccessful()){`? Is the task successful? If so, and you step through the code, what values are passed into `new User(fullName, email, bio, username,location,realstatus,profilePic);`? Do those look correct? If so, is there any error message showing in the logcat output for the `.setValue(user)` call?

Comment: Okay so after stepping through the code, it never reaches task.isSuccessful() and so the the user object is never created. I'm not sure why it's never reaching that point....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments it sounds like `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` fails. When that happens, the task actually contains an exception with more information about the failure - but you're not handling that.

A better way to handle task failure is:

```
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
  if(task.isSuccessful()){
    ...
  }
  else{
    Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Failed to Register User", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.e("Create user", "Failed to create user", task.getException());
  }
  progressBar.setVisibility(ViewStub.GONE);
}
```

With this, the cause of the task failure will show up in your logcat output.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I put the log result into my updated answer. This definitely helps narrow it down but I feel unsure about it because it's saying that I need to specify the Database URL but I'm not really sure where in the documentation it says I need to do that.

Comment: It sounds like the `google-services.json` was downloaded before you created the Realtime Database. I recommend: 1) verifying in the Firebase console that your database was created, 2) re-downloading the `google-services.json` and adding that to your app again. If that doesn't work, you can also try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65558463/firebase-database-points-to-wrong-database-url/65566484#65566484

Comment: How do I verify that the database was created? Do I just click on Runtime DB on the firebase console and see if anything is there? Also, I tried redownloading the json and refactoring but no luck unfortunately. I'll try the link you sent me next.

Comment: I also tried manually copying and pasting the URL into the DB getReffrence and rebuilding the project after replacing the old json with the new one. Still to no avail unfortunately :(

Comment: Yeah, if this console [link](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/) loads anything for the database, it exists. You'll also see the database URL in the data screen in that case. If it doesn't exist, the link will prompt you to create it.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks for letting me know. I appreciate your help.