# I cant add data in Firebase Database through a Fragment with setValue, regarding firebase storage and firebase firestore working

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code in my "AddFragment.java" file for adding data into firebase firestore, firebase storage and firebase database. Regarding firebase storage and firebase firestore working, the firebase database is not working, despite configured properly.

```
imageUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(filePath!=null) {

            String LostPetName = petName.getText().toString().trim();
            String userID = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            String path = userID+"_"+filePath.hashCode()+".jpg";
            StorageReference petPhotos = storageReference.child(path);
            DocumentReference documentReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("Lost_Pets").document(path);
            DatabaseReference myDatabase = firebaseDatabase.getReference("pets");

            //                      -------------------------

            //                      ADDING AN IMAGE START

            petPhotos.putFile(filePath).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Imagine încărcată cu succes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //                      -------------------------

                    //                      ADDING A MAP LatLng START

                    String markerId = myDatabase.push().getKey();
                    AddMarker coord = new AddMarker(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude(), userID);
                    assert markerId != null;
                    myDatabase.child(markerId).setValue(coord);

                    //                      ADDING A MAP LatLng END

                    //                      -------------------------

                    petPhotos.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri downloadUrl)
                        {
                            imgUri = downloadUrl.toString();
                            imgID = imgUri;
                            Map<String,Object> pet = new HashMap<>();
                            pet.put("LostPetName", LostPetName);
                            pet.put("img_id", imgID);
                            pet.put("markerLatitude", String.valueOf(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude()));
                            pet.put("markerLongitude", String.valueOf(lastKnownLocation.getLongitude()));
                            documentReference.set(pet);

                        }
                    });

                }
            })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Eșuare adăugare imagine", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

            //                      ADDING AN IMAGE END

            //                      -------------------------

        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Nu s-a ales o imagine pentru animalul pierdut", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
}
```

If I add a `Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude()) + String.valueOf(lastKnownLocation.getLongitude()) + userID)` there after the `setValue` function I can see my data correctly in the log.

The AddMarker function is as follows.

```
public static class AddMarker {

    public double lat;
    public double lng;
    public String senderUid;

    public AddMarker(double lat, double lng, String senderUid) {
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
        this.senderUid = senderUid;
    }
}
```

I have my firebase configured correctly in my gradle file.

Account connected and implementation set:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.0'
```

and also the rules in Firebase:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

If somebody knows something I don't, please help me. I'd be grateful.

Comment: It is really hard to help with "the firebase database is not working". If you step through your code in a debugger, putting breakpoint on each line, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: myDatabase.child(markerId).setValue(coord);

Comment: What is the value of `coord` at that line? Also: did you [attach a completion listener](https://gist.github.com/puf/4a94a01e3c2510298ee46d0a7f90ab75) yet? What did it do when you stepped into that? Please note that Stack Overflow is a horrible inefficient interactive debugger, so I highly recommend you take a few steps at a time and anticipate what else we might need at each step. It'd also help to read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which contains many more steps to increase the chances someone can help.

Comment: I see in the debugger that it gets my database as "https://rescue-a-soul-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/pets" but my database is "https://rescue-a-soul-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/". Im guessing here is the problem.

Comment: Can you help me with a workaround for this?

Comment: It sounds like you may have downloaded the `google-services.json` before the Realtime Database was created, which may lead to it using the wrong URL. I recommend downloading an updated `google-services.json`, adding _that_ to your Android app, and trying again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment chain it sounds like you may have downloaded the `google-services.json` before the Realtime Database was created, which may lead to it using the wrong URL.

I recommend downloading an updated `google-services.json`, adding *that* to your Android app, and trying again. If that doesn't work, you can also specify the correct URL in the code with `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("rescue-a-soul-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app")...`.

Also see:

- [Firebase Database points to wrong database URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65558463/firebase-database-points-to-wrong-database-url/65566484#65566484)

Comment: This seemed to be the problem... it took me 3 days and i still couldn't get over it without your help, thanks a lot Frank!