# onDataChange loads indefinitely, Firebase in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Following a `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()`, I have a defined an `onDataChange()` method - which insists on loading indefinitely and not returning any data from the database.

I know that `onDataChange()` is asynchronous, and I'm waiting for it to finish, it just doesn't.

This happened suddenly, and without me changing anything, after over 6 months of the method working just fine in my project.

Relevant code attached below:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference usersRef = database.getReference().child("users");

usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (!dataSnapshot.child(userName).exists()) {
            Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this,"Incorrect credentials were entered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        else if (!dataSnapshot.child(userName).child("password").getValue().toString().equals(et_enterPassword.getText().toString())) {
            Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this,"Incorrect credentials were entered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        Intent homePageIntent = new Intent(LogInActivity.this, HomePageActivity.class);

        startActivity(homePageIntent);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
       Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this,"An error occurred!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Tried reinstalling my `google-services.json` file and checking perms for accessing the database, all of which resulted in absolutely nothing.

EDIT:
After enabling Firebase debug logging and further digging it seems like the issue is somehow related to my WIFI.
The error I'm getting is: `com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocketException: unknown host: #####.firebaseio.com` to which I found a corresponding bug report on GitHub, which suggested to use `database.goOffline();` and `database.goOnline();`

Comment: Nothing in the code you shared explains the behavior you describe, so it'll be hard for anyone here to help. Please edit your question to include the [minimal complete/standalone code+data that is needed for any of us to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Edited as per requested, although I don't really understand how what I do with the data is relevant.

I'll try to elaborate a bit more:
As far as I know and understand, `onDataChange` executes as soon as Firebase returns the `DataSnapshot` - the issue is that it doesn't execute, no matter how long I wait for.. and since it worked perfectly before I really have no clue what is causing it.

Comment: That code looks fine indeed, so it's unlikely the problem is in there (something we can only know once we've seen the code, hence the ask for it). I don't think anything changed in the Realtime Database backend in those six months that would explain a change in behavior like what you describe though, so it's still most likely something change in the client-side behavior. I recommend [enabling debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) and checking the logcat output.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen After enabling debug logging and further digging it seems like the issue is somehow related to my WIFI..?
The error I'm getting is:
`com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocketException: unknown host: #####.firebaseio.com`
to which I found a corresponding bug report on GitHub, which suggested to use
`database.goOffline();` and `database.goOnline();`, but without specifying where.
Any suggestions?

[Mentioned GitHub page](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1258)

Comment: Troubleshooting steps: 0) Please edit your question with the additional information you found above. Other potential helpers are not likely to see them in these comments. 1) Are you sure your device has a stable internet connection? 2) Are you sure you have the correct URL for your database configured either in the code of your app, or in the `google-services.json` file? If you're not certain: try the first option I gave here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65566484.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Tried running the app again on my laptop while connected to a different network and it worked just fine. 
It indeed appears that the issue is with the stability of the internet connection on my Desktop, should've checked that before asking I guess..
Really appreciate the help and the patience, especially considering the actual problem.

Comment: Good to hear you found the cause of the problem Daniel!  